# cant import netsnmp in python on centos 6.5

Tags: python, centos, net-snmp

I am trying to use netsnmp in python but it is unable to import after following all suggestions related to netsnmp in python. I installed netsnmp using below commands

```
yum install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
easy_install ipython
```

snmpd service is running.
It still throws this error

```
ImportError: No module named netsnmp
```

I am using Cent os 6.5 and Python version 2.6.6
Kindly help if installation is incorrect or any other configuration is missing.

Comment: You need to install the net-snmp-python package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import netsnmp in python only *net-snmp-python* is required both *net-snmp net-snmp-utils* can be removed.
so just

```
yum install net-snmp-python
```

will do for importing netsnmp library into python on Cent os 6.5

```
yum install net-snmp net-snmp-utils
```

will enable SNMP queries from Linux terminal.
Both can work independently.